# Sequelize - Can not set custom field name with Sync({alter: true})

Tags: sequelize.js

Sequelize sync({alter: true}) is creating the field with name as underscored in the database intially. Later it is dropping the field and adding the same field with the name as camelCase.

Is there any other way to indicate custom field name for Sync alter ?

```
// User Model
module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {
    var User = sequelize.define('User', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        userName: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            field: 'user_name'
        }
      }
    });
  return User;
};
```